# What are the result of having the parent of the parent in Maven

Tags: maven, parent, pom.xml

I have in Maven POM files :

- The artifact **A** is the parent of the artifact **B**
- The artifact **B** is the parent of the artifact **C**

Can C get the dependencies of A?

In general, what are the results on the artifact **C**?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Maven project inherits (almost) all elements of its parent's pom, which in turn inherits from its respective parent and so on, up to Super POM (see http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.1/maven-model-builder/).

So yes, a dependency defined in A would lead to a dependency in C.

Note however, that defining dependencies (not dependency management) in a parent project is mostly a bad idea, since you cannot prevent your child from inheriting them, potentially leading to unnecessary dependencies. For that reason, you should at the most include test and provided-scoped dependencies in your parents.

Comment: So do you mean that if we put the dependencies in "dependency management" of the parent pom, the child won't inherit those dependencies?

Comment: @GotACrushOnIT Yes. It would inherit the dependency manangement block, but this would not lead to a dependency. A dependency management block is used to say: If I or one of my child projects use has this dependency, it should use it with THIS version (and THESE exclusions). That way, you define all your relevant versions in one project, your parent and ommit versions in your child. Your dependencies stay consistent, but still every project explicitly states its dependencies.

Comment: nice explaination. +1

Answer (score 2):

According to Maven dependency mechanism a child POM inherits the dependencies of Parent POM

***"There is no limit to the number of levels that dependencies can be gathered from ..."***

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

So artifact C will have all the dependencies of artifact B and artifact A.

Regards
Jyotsna

Comment: ahh right thats for plugins configuration not for dependencies .Thanks for correcting me :)

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. +1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, dependencies are inherited from all ancestor projects.  To help determine a project's actual dependencies, the [Maven Help Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/) provides the [effective-pom](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html) goal.  When the `effective-pom` goal is executed, Maven outputs the effective POM for the current build complete with active profile settings and all parent POM settings factored in.  To execute the goal, simply run:

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

From the output you will see all the dependencies, direct, inherited and transitive, needed for the current build.

If you do this from the **C** project directory, the output will contain the dependencies from project **C**, any inherited dependencies from project **B** and, any additional inherited dependencies from project **A**.